# Have a subdomain used only for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, cloudflare

That's how I built my website in the web form and I want to build it on MVC and I have ssl by CloudFlare, but I would like to have a subdomain used for only MVC.

How can I build it up so that I make an MVC site which will be the new part so it must be a folder for himself as my website does not go down but matter to show the new system to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About the SSL issue:

Adding SSL If you also want to add an SSL binding to the wildcard domain, the certificate must be a wildcard certificate to cover the full breadth of the wildcard domain. 
[image]

And about the APP itself, you can map your Azure Web App to a sub domain.
You can use this article to do that:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/waws/archive/2014/10/01/mapping-a-sub-domain-to-an-azure-web-site.aspx